# python 3.10 reconnect to socket / create new socket instance / windows 10

Tags: python, sockets, tcp

```
import socket
import time
import os
import subprocess
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from threading import Thread
import threading
    
HOST = '149.253.61.28'
PORT = 30002
    
global connected
connected = False

global s
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

print("not connected")

global gui1
gui1=0

def showGUI():
    global gui1
    gui1 = Tk(className="socket test")
    gui1.geometry("500x300")
    butreconn = Button(gui1, text='RECONNECT', borderwidth=3, command = reconn)
    butreconn.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.6, width=240, height=80, anchor=CENTER)

def reconn():
    global connected
    global s
    global gui1
    p = subprocess.Popen("netstat -a -n -o |find \"" + HOST + ":" + str(PORT) + "\"", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]
    print("socket ProcessID: " + p.decode('UTF-8')[-8:].lstrip())
    os.system("taskkill /PID " + p.decode('UTF-8')[-8:].lstrip())
    showGUI()
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    connected = False

showGUI()

class pr1(Thread):
    def run(self):
        while True:
            global connected
            global s
            if(not connected):
                try:
                    s.connect((HOST, PORT))
                    print("connected")
                    connected = True
                except:
                    pass
            else:
                try:
                    s.send(("set_digital_out(1,True)"+"\n").encode('utf8'))
                    time.sleep(0.3)
                    s.send(("set_digital_out(1,False)"+"\n").encode('utf8'))
                    time.sleep(0.3)
                except:
                    print("not connected")
                    connected = False
                    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
                    pass


pr1().start()
event = threading.Event()
gui1.mainloop()
```

This reconnects on its own after I physically disconnected/reconnected the RJ45 connector.
However, if I set the Client (receiver of these commands, a robot controller) to local and back to remote it won't work anymore, I need to restart the script. I think the OS (Windows 10) blocks the socket. It might work to create a new socket like s[n..1] or make another script that restarts this script to reconnect but I am sure there are people here that can tell how to do it right.

EDIT:
Now I can reconnect with a button manually. It kills the socket through the windows shell first before it creates a new one. But the command os.system(..) will kill the tkinter GUI too?
My workaround is the showGUI() function to reinitialize the GUI but one can notice the window closing and reopening.

Comment: Will make a new thread for the GUI issue

Comment: You need to close the socket after a connection failure.

Comment: That's exactly what this script does