# python 3.10 "os.system" command kills tkinter GUI

Tags: python, tkinter, os.system

While I figured [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71844624/python-3-10-reconnect-to-socket-create-new-socket-instance-windows-10) out by myself, I am stuck with another problem.

As soon as `os.system("taskkill /PID " + p.decode('UTF-8')[-8:].lstrip())` gets executed, the tkinter GUI gets shutdown. The actual issue might be called earlier during creation of a subprocess.

```
def reconn():
    global connected
    global s
    p = subprocess.Popen("netstat -a -n -o |find \"" + HOST + ":" + str(PORT) + "\"", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]
    os.system("taskkill /PID " + p.decode('UTF-8')[-8:].lstrip())
    showGUI()
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    connected = False
```

the showGUI() function simply reopens the GUI, which wouldn't be necessary if it won't close in the first place.

Check out the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71844624/python-3-10-reconnect-to-socket-create-new-socket-instance-windows-10) for the full code.

Comment: I am stuck here, can someone please help. Reloading the GUI creates other Problems and isn't the right approach. Most likely "taskkill" kills the GUI, so how to use it just for closing the blocked socket?

Comment: I solved this finally. I execute another script called killsocket.py as a new instance. os.system("python killsocket.py"). This script ends with os._exit(#PID of socket)